# Does Bitlocker qualify as the 'Cryptographic Module' defined in FIPS140-2?

Tags: encryption, fips

Wikipedia defines [Bitlocker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitLocker_Drive_Encryption) as:

> BitLocker Drive Encryption is a full disk encryption feature included
>   with the Ultimate and Enterprise editions of Microsoft's Windows Vista
>   and Windows 7 desktop operating systems, as well as the Windows Server
>   2008 and Windows Server 2008 R2 server platforms. It is designed to
>   protect data by providing encryption for entire volumes.

I've heard that some maybe using Bitlocker for drive encryption in order to comply with [FIPS 140-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIPS_140-2).

> The National Institute of Standards and Technology (NIST) issued the
>   FIPS 140 Publication Series to coordinate the requirements and
>   standards for cryptography modules that include both hardware and
>   software components.

Does **Bitlocker** qualify as the **cryptographic module** defined in FIPS 140-2?

Are there any other pieces that are needed to fulfill the need for FIPS 140-2 security level 1 'cryptographic module' requirements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bitlocker is a FIPS 140-2 certified module with [certificate](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cmvp/documents/140-1/140crt/140crt1339.pdf) number [1339](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cmvp/documents/140-1/140val-all.htm#1339).  It is important for you to read the [FIPS security policy](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cmvp/documents/140-1/140sp/140sp1339.pdf) to determine if the operating conditions conform to your environment.  For example:

> The BitLocker™ components (Windows Server 2008 R2 versions: 6.1.7600.16385, 6.1.7600.16429, 
> 6.1.7600.16757, 6.1.7600.20536, 6.1.7600.20873, 6.1.7600.20897 and 6.1.7600.20916; SP1 versions: 6.1.7601.17514, 6.1.7601.17556, 6.1.7601.21634, 6.1.7601.21655 and 6.1.7601.21675) identified in section 4 **have been validated on the Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 and Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 on x64**.

Comment: Usually it's some regulation thing "you must use FIPS 140-2 compliant security measures." in some contract or something.

Comment: @ewanm89 I'm not sure what you mean, here.  Did you mean to comment on my answer or to the original question?

Comment: It also depends on the region it's being used in: but that is somewhat obvious.